# Solving literal equation involving reciprocal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am asked to solve for y

The equation is:

X= 4y/3y-1

If you could please show step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x = \frac{4y}{3y-1} => x(3y-1) = 4y => 3xy - x = 4y$

Therefore, $3xy - 4y = x => y(3x-4) = x$

Therefore, $y = \frac{x}{3x-4}$

Hoping this is what you meant by "solve for $y$."

Note also: this is assuming $3y-1 \neq 0$ and $3x-4 \neq 0$, because in each case, either $x$ is undefined, or $y$ is undefined, respectively.

Comment: Yes thank you!!

Comment: First line: Not if $y= \frac13$.  Nor, for $x = \frac 43$

Comment: That is correct, I assumed they're both non-zero, but I'll make that clear, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the edits yet again @amWhy.

Comment: No worries, S.walia.  In fact you deleted it just as I was about to post my comment.

Answer (score 0):

$x = \dfrac{4y}{3y-1}$ corresponds to the fractional linear transformation of $(\Bbb Q)\Bbb P^1$ with matrix $\begin{pmatrix}4&0\\3&-1\end{pmatrix}$, whose inverse is $\dfrac1{-4}\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\-3&4\end{pmatrix}$, corresponding to the function $y = \dfrac{-x}{-3x+4}$, which is the inverse required.

(Note also: this is assuming $3y-1 \neq 0$ and $3x-4 \neq 0$, because in each case, either $x$ is undefined, or $y$ is undefined, respectively.)

Comment: Not if $y= \frac13$.  Nor, for $x = \frac 43$

Comment: @amWhy actually, in $\Bbb{QP}^1$, those two values are perfectly fine.